# Auto-fill uses half the cores

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-interop, excel-dna

I'm autofilling some columns in Excel (one at a time).  These column use a UDF I wrote in ExcelDna.  Using taskmanager, I notice that only half of the cores are being used.  Excel settings is set to "use all processors on this computer."  So I can't figure out why only half the cores are in use.  Thoughts?

Comment: Does the task manager make clear which "processors" are hyper-thread siblings of which others? Consider an i7 processor; it has four cores and hyperthreading, so it _looks_ like 8 processors but there are only four instruction decoders, four ALUs, four FPUs, four caches, etc. Using all _8_ available will not necessarily give a performance increase over using the _4_ physical things that exist. Has Excel chosen to simply use the _physical_ cores and ignore the siblings?

Comment: good question!  I actually turn-off hyperthreading in the BIOS.  My box has two CPUs, each with 6 cores.  So total 12 physical cores which is what Excel shows in settings.

Comment: Zounds. What a machine. :) Any chance it is using the cores from a single CPU and ignoring the other socket entirely? Is there _any_ kind of pattern to which cores are being used? (I wouldn't be shocked if the internals weren't expecting 12 cores...)

Comment: Its a beauty, and it hurts not be run at 100% =)  It looks like only the cores from one processor are being used (if windows arranges the cores consecutively).  I've seen it use the first 6 and the last 6.  strange huh?

Comment: instead of autofill, i prefer to copy & paste special as formulas all columns while calculation is set to manual and then recalculate - i didn't time it nor try it on 12 cores, but at least excel shows a percentage indicator in the status bar this way ;)

Comment: Its best to avoid copy/paste when automating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page contains some insightful explainations about multi-processing in Excel 2007+
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa730921(v=office.12).aspx#office2007excelperf_ExcelPerformanceImprovements

**Ref: "Multithreaded Calculations"
"Some Excel features do not use multithreaded calculation, for example:
Data table calculation (but structured references to tables do use MTC).
User-defined functions (but XLL functions can be multithread-enabled).
XLM functions.
INDIRECT, CELL functions that use either the format2 or address options.
GETPIVOTDATA and other functions referring to PivotTables or cubes.
Range.Calculate and Range.CalculateRowMajorOrder.
Cells in circular reference loops.* "

Since it doesn't specifically describe "autofill" - I'll take a crack at it from a concurrency perspective. Please forgive if some of this is speculation..

Certain functions require an "in-order" task that cannot easily be split across processors, we might suspect that fill is one of them. (It requires sequential operation in some of it's modes.. example: stepping 1,1.2,1.4,etc). In this example, processor 2 can't just start from the middle of the page without performing a new/custom independant calculation. Special functions would have to be designed. Perhaps they decided not to code for these kinds of scenerios. With formulas I can't see this even being possible, because you could be creating a formula tree.

Other operations are indepentant based on the formula trees (see link). This strongly implies Excel won't multi-process a complext formula tree either .. so if you have numerous formulas connected, they (that tree) will be only be processsed, in order, by one processor.

Granted, there's all kinds of complex work-arounds for these situations.. (perhaps similiar to compilers, SQL servers, etc) but the documentation above is highly suggestive that Microsoft designed it to streamline independant tasks only.